# Want to upload file in the live server other than App_Data folder in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, image-upload

I need to upload an image in **~/Images/Item** folder in live server. I can upload in **~/App_Data/Images** folder without any exception. But when I'm trying to upload in **~/Images/Item**, it gives me exception with message `"A generic error occurred in GDI+"`.

I have searched already but did not find any solution that worked for me. Any kind of suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Please show more exception details (including stack trace if necessary). GDI+ generic error when saving image file usually thrown from "access denied to target directory", probably you need write permission enabled on `/Images/Item` directory with current user.

Comment: Thanks. I have communicated with the hosting owner, and they have provided extra read and write permission for me. It's working now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Pleasemake sure that that application have write permission to this folder.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file) {
 // Verify that the user selected a file
 if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) {
  // extract only the filename
  var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
  // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
  var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Item"), fileName);
  file.SaveAs(path);
 }

 return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have communicated with the hosting owner, and they have provided extra read and write permission for me. It's working now. :)